# Creating pdf_tex file with Inkscape, problems with Font Sizes

Tags: fonts, inkscape, size

I am currently trying to find out how to create pictures while using the latex font. As the title shows I am using Inkscape and the pdf_tex_function to do so.

When I import the pictures in Latex, obviously the font size is set to the Latex default font size. But the pictures will look differently if the font sizes in the Latex files are different. If I draw a picture, which fits perfectly for 12 pt font size, it won't be fine when the document got 5 pt. So I would have to change the picture and make it smaller, so that the font size also gets smaller and reaches 5 pt in Inkscape.

Is it possible to avoid that? I mean, isn't it possible to create a picture with any size and fitting it in latex proportionally?

I have some Examples attached.

[image: Inkscape comparison with different Latex font sizes]

Also I have written the following simple code, for the picture, which I created to be perfect for 12 pt.

```
\documentclass[final, 5pt, twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
%% Include a pic with 12 pt Text in Inkscape
        {\input{12pttex.pdf_tex}} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```